# Mantain Storage of a list of strings in a cell

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing problem in storing a list of strings for my python application. I am looking for a solution to store my dataframe offline like a csv file with a cell containing a List of strings. Can someone suggest any data structure or file format where i may be able to easily access, edit and save my dataframe

i have tried to store the dataframe in a csv file but on reading the data from csv file converts the list of strings into a single string

My dataframe

```
          Error               Comments
         ["A1","A2","A3']     "Answer1"
         ["A3","A2","A1"]     "Answer2"
```

Comment: depends on the data. but maybe json?

Comment: Show us how you reading this csv

Comment: Will json mantain the integrity of the list of strings alike csv format where a list of strings will be stored as a single string?

Comment: @sygneto i am just using pandas.read_csv function to read and pandas.to_csv to store data

Comment: I know that you using that but read_csv has many options , so if you give us example how you doing that and what you want to get, that would be helpful